# GCP pubsub (java) authentication error happens after entering the running state. Why?

Tags: java, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

So a pubsub subscription can be in one of the following states: `NEW`, `STARTING`, `RUNNING`, `STOPPING`, `FAILED` and `TERMINATED`.

When I create such subscription, I want to wait for it to enter the RUNNING state before returning. I'm using kotlin coroutines in order to avoid blocking threads.

However the Subscription enters the Running state before failing for bad credentials, giving the false impression that the Subscription started running correctly when it actually didn't. Why is it that? And how can I circumvent that?

Is there a way to try the credentials before starting the Subscription?

Comment: Can you clarify where or how did you see the states of the subscription? Can you share a working code for your use case? Just so it could be reproduced and easily understood by the community.

Comment: PubSub subscription haven't states on GCP. However, it's possible that the client has states in the Java library. Anyway, if your subscription fail, the status should no longer be RUNNING, but FAILED, and you should get that state and not rely on the previous one, RUNNING before the credential issue. It's a pure Kotlin and coroutines issue and sharing a piece of code to reproduce the issue on our side could be great!

Comment: It's actually not a kotlin issue. I want to initialize the subscription and wait for the running event to happen to consider initialization completed. However, barely after it started "running" it enters into "failed" state given the fact that I'm providing wrong credentials. That makes the whole app start like initialization went well. Healthchecks in the app actually report a failure and that's good. But I still think that error shouldn't go in the Healthchecks, but happen during initialization

Comment: @AlejandroNavas as what Ricco and Guillaume mentioned, please provide a piece of  working code to reproduce the issue. We cannot help as it's difficult to guess what your code looks like.